# Is it possible to use regexp as object property?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the following object:

```
var map = {};
map[/^\/e\/(?:([0-9a-f]{24}))\/rename\/?$/] = "/e/531e8942711f533cf0000019/rename";
```

The object above is mapping regex to testing value. I need to make something like the following:

```
for (var i in map) {
   if (map.hasOwnProperty(i) && i.test(map[i])) {
      console.log('It works');
   }
}
```

But the code above doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `i.test(map[i])` words? I think it does not...

Comment: @PlasmaPower Hence the question.

Comment: A RegExp object is not a string.

Comment: @tenub Using it as a property name will invoke its `.toString()` method, which *will* be a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var map = {};
map["^/e/(?:([0-9a-f]{24}))/rename/?$"] = "/e/531e8942711f533cf0000019/rename";

for (var i in map) {
   if (map.hasOwnProperty(i) && (new RegExp(i)).test(map[i])) {
      console.log('It works');
   }
}
// prints: It works
```

Comment: You will lose the ability to add modifiers if you do this.

Comment: For what OP is using it for it should be fine but yes it is better to use better storage in map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can; however, one thing to take note of is that regular expressions are first cast into a string before they're being used as a property name.

So when you want to use a property name as an expression again you must "rehydrate" it first:

```
for (var i in map) {
   if (map.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       var re = eval(i);
       if (re.test(map[i])) {
         console.log('It works');
       }
   }
}
```

However, I would recommend using arrays instead to prevent this "magical" conversion to and fro:

```
var map = [];
map.push([/^\/e\/(?:([0-9a-f]{24}))\/rename\/?$/, "/e/531e8942711f533cf0000019/rename"]);

map.forEach(function(info) {
    if (info[0].match(info[1])) {
       console.log('it works');
    }
});
```